# Is it OK to use multiple modifiers for a class in BEM?

Tags: css, bem

Is it ok to add multiple modifiers to an element in BEM like this:

```
my-item__icon--open--not-red
```

As you can see I added **--open** and **--not-red** to **my-item__icon**.
Is this ok?
Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: This is subjective since BEM is mainly a form of style guide. I don't see a problem with multiple modifiers personally.

Comment: BEM It's not a law carved on the stone, but personally I would decouple that modifier into `my-item__icon--open` and `my-item__icon--not-red` and I would apply both. Just a matter of taste and context.

Comment: Aren't modifiers supposed to be applied to blocks like `my-item--open`. not to elements as in the question.

Comment: @Batu.Khan, In my example two modifiers are added to the same block.

Answer (score 6):

It is ok to have multiple modifiers on a single element, but it should only be one modifier per selector. Don't forget that modifiers can only be added as a new selectors to an existing element selector: `<div class="my-item__icon my-item__icon--open my-item__icon--not-red">`.
Source/example: https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#element-modifier-name

Then you probably want to style them one by one:

```
.my-item__icon {display: none;}
.my-item__icon--open {display: inline;}
.my-item__icon--not-red {color: blue;}
```

Comment: If the multiple classes for each modifier bothers you, I built a Sass library that will allow OP to use their initial single class: https://github.com/One-Nexus/Cell/wiki